# Add HTML code in .html files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, inject

I'm developing a website with bootstrap.
If I want to modify the navbar, I don't want to go to any html files and make changes.
So would like to use javascript to "inject" the html code into the actual html file but I don't know how to do it.

This is what I tried.

```js
document.write("<p>html code here</p>")
```

It, however, doesn't work. What the most conveniente and simple solution could be?

Comment: There are many. Consider researching into any libraries or frameworks?

Comment: don't ever use `document.write` - [it does not do what you think, and it's from the very first days of JS, before we knew better](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript). It's 2021, learn how to use the DOM API (createElement, append, etc). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) is your friend, start with [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), read the example, and take it from there.

Comment: Use a static site generator for this sort of thing. Don't use client-side JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this example below:

```
let newElement = document.createElement('div');

newElement.className = 'new-element';
```

This will create a div - assign it to the variable named 'newElement' and creating a class associated with that element named "new-element".